# Need help creating a fourth splitter

Tags: formula, formula-field

I have a field that contains 4 values that are comma separated: Value1, value2, value3, value4.
I am currently able to dissect the first 3 values but am having trouble getting the  fourth one.
Here is my current first value extraction:

```
TRIM(LEFT( api_name__c , FIND(",", api_name__c)-1))
```

Second:

```
    LEFT(RIGHT( api_name__c , LEN(api_name__c) - FIND (",", api_name__c)), 
    FIND("," , RIGHT(api_name__c, LEN(api_name__c) - FIND (",", api_name__c)))-1)
```

Third:

```
   LEFT(RIGHT( api_name__c , LEN(RIGHT(api_name__c, LEN(api_name__c) - FIND (",",
   api_name__c))) - FIND (",", RIGHT(api_name__c, LEN(api_name__c) - FIND (",", 
   api_name__c)))), FIND("," , RIGHT(api_name__c, LEN(RIGHT(api_name__c, 
   LEN(api_name__c) - FIND (",", api_name__c))) - FIND (",", RIGHT(api_name__c,
   LEN(api_name__c) - FIND (",", api_name__c)))))-1)
```

How can I extract the fourth value?

Comment: As I believe the link in your previous iteration of this question indicated, this really is a job better suited for Apex. Must you use a formula here?

Comment: Yes, it needs to be a formula

Comment: Can you go into more detail about why a formula is required? Also, what have you tried so far to get at the 4th value? (you should [edit] your question to include what you've tried so far).

Comment: and what happens when requirements change and the business needs 5 (or 6 or more) values split?  Formulas are not going to help here and even if you arrive at one, the coding will be opaque to the next admin who inherits this.

Comment: There can only be a maximum of 4 values in this field. Here is how you can trim the 4th value: RIGHT( Combination_of_Rated_Skills__c , FIND(",", Combination_of_Rated_Skills__c)-1)

Comment: This trim however is not accurate as it will grab everything from the right even if the 4th value is not there and overlap on the third. I need this to work with the same logic as the 3rd trim